# How to detect multiple mobile inputs at the same time with Godot?

Tags: mobile, godot

In the game I am currently making, the player will frequently need to press two buttons at the same time, for example "jump" and "left". Currently I have two buttons on the left side of the screen for left and right, and one on the right for jump. The problem is, if the player is pressing any of them, it effectively locks the other buttons, making it so you can't press them.

Is there some way, perhaps using `InputEventScreenTouch`, that I can detect the user's current touchscreen input every frame, and check if they are pressing one or more buttons?

Edit for more info:
Currently each button sends it's `button_down()` and `button_up()` signals to the same function in the HUD scene root, and I have simple functions to handle that:

```
func setLeft(val):
    # This is the variable that the player
    # checks each frame to see if it should move
    self.get_parent().get_parent().goingLeft = val
```

So when the player starts pressing the left button, it sets `goingLeft` to `true`, and when they release it it sets `goingLeft` to `false`.

This should work fine, but I have discovered that if the player is touching the screen anywhere else, the buttons don't register input. For example, if I press the left button, the player starts going left, and then while I am holding that, I start pressing jump. The jump button doesn't register, because my finger is already pressing somewhere else on the screen (the left one).

It doesn't seem to matter if it is a button that I am pressing, just that Godot will only check buttons if there is exactly one input.

Is there some way to get around this?

Comment: Yes you need to put your code mate ! Thanks

Comment: Umm. I can't find the edit button for my question lol. How do I do that?

Comment: edit button is just under the tags

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe I missed that xD

Comment: It happens sometimes ahah

Comment: Does it make any difference if you uncheck the "Emulate Mouse from Touch" in the project settings?

Comment: PS: I see there's a `TouchScreenButton` node class. Have you tried it? Does it make a difference if you use that or a `Button`?

Comment: If both of those things fail, there's another approach you can take. Look at the last answer here: https://godotengine.org/qa/28958/someone-please-explain-handling-trying-analog-stick-scene?show=29582#a29582

Comment: Thank you for the reply! My GPU recently broke, and I will try those things as soon as I get my new one! xD

Answer (score 3):

I have found the solution, thanks to some people in the comments!

I changed the button types to `TouchScreenButton` nodes, and they have multitouch enabled, so I can press more than one at once, on a mobile device!